# Java heap space error when using command line but not Eclipse

Tags: java, command, line, heap-memory

I am writing a Java program which executes an open source jar file. I have written the following program:

```
    public class RunMain {


public RunMain(String []prams)
{
   runMain(prams);
}

public runMain (String [] prams) throwsException
{

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process proc;  

String command ="java -jar -Xmx10g jarfilename.jar main prams [parameters for the main file]";

proc = rt.exec(command);

}

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

    new RunMain(args);
}
```

The program runs perfectly on Eclipse (the setting in eclipse.ini are:
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m). However when I use the command line e.g. cmd or cygwin to run the program or type in the command directly, I get the following error:
Main:Error:Java heap space

It is clear that the open source program is installed and working correctly because it runs from Eclipse on the same machine. Can anyone help me debugging this?

Comment: Do you need 10GB of memory? Does your PC have it available?

Comment: The runMain parameter `parms` is never used, and I'm not certain, but wouldn't the eclipse.ini file only specify the eclipse IDE, and not program configuration? I believe that's specified in the VM arguments section on run configurations. Are you getting 10GB? I'd open up resource monitor and monitor memory usage.

Comment: The RAM on my PC is 32GB.

Comment: The parameters (prams) are used inside the string command.

Comment: what does your `java -version` tell you? Do you have a 64bit version of Java running when invoking the command in your console? Eclipse often ships which its own Java version or other JVMs can be specified

Comment: java version "1.8.0_45". I thought that eclipse uses the installed java version on the machine.